# Video Streaming, how to limit users by time

Tags: video, streaming, chat

I am developing a video streaming website, my problem is how do i limit users by time, like if they have credit balance for 3 hours of streaming, how to i stop or pause the streaming once the credit is used up.

Ideas anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it would be a lot handier if you would supply information such as the technologies you would be using. You would require to be build some methods, like for one blocking the page content for a video player ID, if the credit is not sufficient.

Comment: I am using flex with red5, to stream video, if we can do it better with silverlight please suggest.